# if statement syntax in Javascript jQuery .each function

Tags: javascript

(very new to JavaScript jQuery)

Can an if statement contain a collection of other functions, specifically .each functions? If yes, is there something wrong with my implementation?

```
var string2 = "domain";
var mainpath = (window.location.href);

if (mainpath.indexOf(string2))  {

    $("#topnav a").each(function(){                         
        var thishref = $(this).attr('href');    
        $(this).attr({href: thishref + '?lnkid=tnav'}); 
    });

    $("#nav a").each(function(){                            
        var thishref = $(this).attr('href');    
        $(this).attr({href: thishref + '?lnkid=pnav'});
    });

}
```

What I want to do is run the code inside the if statement only when the page is at my domain (rather than inside the development space of a cms).
-Thanks

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but you can compare directly to `window.location.host`

Comment: An if statement may contain any other statement, e.g. the block statement, which in turn contains a list of zero or more statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure it can.  You are doing it basically correct.  A suggestion:

Be explicit with your if conditional, so do something like

```
if (mainPath.indexOf(string2) !== -1) {...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, nothing wrong with it. but it can be easily tricked with the following URL:

`http://www.other.tld/?domain`

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly valid to use an `if` to conditionally run code. Though there seems to be an issue with your condition:

```
if (mainpath.indexOf(string2))
```

The index of string2 within mainpath can be `0` which would prevent your code from executing and that's certainly not what you want.

Rather test like this:

```
if ( mainpath.indexOf > -1 ) ...
```

Comment: In this case (because of the guaranteed output of window.location.href) this would only happen if the domain was "http", so while this is worth mentioning, it's not an issue here specifically

Comment: @Gareth Granted, this would hardly ever happen (who'd name his domain httpfoo, right?). After all this could be an easily overlooked source of failure, so we should just do it the right way, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can add a query to each link like this:

```
$("#topnav a").each(function(){                         
    this.search = 'lnkid=tnav';    
});
```

There is no need for a roundabout way involving getting the href attribute, appending to it, and putting it back.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZpMz/1/

Comment: Thanks for this! I struggled with this part of the code too. I wish I knew why/how it works, but I see it works very well.